# change color of parent element when hover over child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mega menu which which show drop0down menus when one hover over the parent menu and when one hover over the dropdown sub menus it then show respective menu related infromation in a a container div with class `dd-panel`

I am change the background color of sub menu's on hover to green and i want it to remain green if one moves cursor over the text or image of this particular menu.

You will also notice that i select/show first element of dropdown ul li as default when one hover ober the parent menu elements.

I want background / foreround color of active menu to meain green/white when one hover over the image or text.

Link for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/13/)

I tried to use following jquery to keep the color of the font to yellow fo rtest person to see if it works. but it is not works.

```
$(".dd-panel").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest("a").toggleClass("menuActive")
});
```

Over view of hole mega menu. I want functionality of the menu to be similar to what it is right now on fiddle but i would appreciate a more professional approach to the coding. I managed so far with the help of stack user since i am not and expert in designer or jquery users i am more of a back-end developer. So any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

UPDATE:

When i  use `$(this).parent(".dropdown ul li").css("border", "2px red solid");`  it works and add's boredr around

but when i use 
  `$(this).parent(".dropdown ul li a").css("color", "red");` it doent' work

Answer (score 1):

Your `<a>` tag is a sibling tag of your `.dd-panel`, not your parent tag.

You should try this:

```
$(".dd-panel").hover(function() {
    $(this).prev("a").toggleClass("menuActive");
});
```

This should toggle your class correctly.

This is also the reason why `$(this).parent(".dropdown ul li").css("border", "2px red solid");` works and `$(this).parent(".dropdown ul li a").css("color", "red");` does not.

Comment: It works this, but i am confused. i also used `closest` which didn't work. I would appreciate if you can tell me how can i make the first element color as green or like the same as as in menuActive class +1 for explanation

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: this toggles your class correctly, check http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/14/ ,you see the back ground is correct.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: it has problem with the font color somehow. I guess there is a problem somewhere in your css that overrides this color.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: `closest` gets the closest parent, not sibling

Comment: I did fix issue with the color as on of the css property was set to important. which was overriding other properties. Thanks for your solution it works anyways.  What about the other part how can i make first `dropdown ul li a` color/background as in the menuActive class.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker:I think that you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/5eecT/15/ . I did that by removing `.nav li:hover > a` in your css